# change my web application's url

Tags: php, http, https

I have a web application developed by php. I can access the application by making use of the url like `http://www.example.com` . Now I need whenever, user types `example.com` in the url it will show `https://www.example.com` instead of `http://www.example.com` . 
Is it possible or I have to take care about `https` from beginning itself during code development?
Please help me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its because you have got ssl certificate .. in some case you need to care about it

Comment: you can simply redirect to the main page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it in htaccess

for web server with domain

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^https://www.example.com/(.*)$
 RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI}  https://www.example.com/$1 [S=1,L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [A-Z]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

for local server

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^https://localhost/(.*)$
 RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI}  https://localhost/$1 [S=1,L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [A-Z]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://localhost/kernel/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have the url like http://localhost/alertR/admins/ and as u told I have done accordingly. in my .htaccess file, I typed like 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/alertR/admins/ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [A-Z]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://localhost/alertR/admins/$1 [R=301,L]
But it is not working.

Comment: @Srim I put htaccess for local server too

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have written the above code only. I am using xampp in my local system and I install it in my C drive. Under htdocs one of the folders is alertR. I keep my .htaccess file under that alertR folder.
Now the problem is, if I try to run this application by localhost/alertR, it's changing to https but the whole url is becoming https://localhost/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/ then obviously, I got Object not found! error.
So what will be the solution? Could you please check that?

Comment: @Srim I thought your HttPs Root is Different from Http Root. Now it is not important in this new change of my htaccess code

Comment: Actually regarding this scenario I am new. Could you please let me know how to check the root of the HttPs.
For a kind information, I have another application(joomla) under that htdocs. When I am trying to open that folder, its taking https and working properly.

Comment: You Can Change https Root In Apache config .and you Can set my htaccess code for Special directory that only one directory has https .with add name of directory like **kernel**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24313/discussion-between-srim-and-mohammad-mohsenipur)

Answer (score 3):

Have your server issue an HTTP 301 status with a Location header redirecting to the HTTPS site.

You can do this at the PHP level with the `header` function, but I'd do it at the web server level. In Apache HTTPD (you didn't specify your server) that just requires `Redirect 301 / https://example.com/` in the virtual host configuration for the port 80 HTTP site.

(NB: The Apache Redirect directive will maintain the rest of the URI, so `http://example.com/foo` will redirect to `https://example.com/foo` and so on)